# Is there a site for getting help with learning to use Blender?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a question about my Blender Stack Exchange post: [Is there any instructional/tutorial articles or videos for face mocap?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156290/is-there-any-instructional-tutorial-articles-or-videos-for-face-mocap)

I had the impression that's what this site was for, but when I asked a question about something I am trying to learn to do, it got deleted for being "not allowed", and replaced with something unrelated. I've tried the other sites on https://www.blender.org/community/, but they seem to have nearly zero users/activity in their forums and have proven to be similarly useless. So, is there any place someone can go for help learning to use blender, or is it more like every blender user has to go into it completely blind and do their best to figure it out on their own?

Please keep in mind that this site doesn't let me make responses (it uses some obscure "reputation points" system to lock me out) so I probably won't be able to answer questions or provide further details once I post this. If you know of any site or other way that someone can get help learning to use blender, please share!

Comment: Have you tried using https://blender.chat, it is a portal into the blender IRC channel.

Answer (score 3):

Hello and thanks for posting here and bringing up the issue.

Blender Stack Exchange *is* the place to ask questions about Blender, and learn using it.
This is no regular forum however, and there a [few strict rules](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to help create a high quality Q&A knowledge database, rather that just casual conversation compendium.

You question was closed for being a request for tutorais which strictly speaking is not really a question about using Blender and is [considered off topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). It can either be answered with a basic Google search, or if it requires a full blown tutorial, it is considered too broad and complex and as such cannot effectively be answered here. These are generally linked to a [generic community approved list of resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender) which among other content includes links for known quality tutorials and videos by reputed authors.

I'd recommend [taking the tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour)  to better understand how this site works. This may seem unfriendly but do come back if you have focused questions about any specific issues or difficulties you encounter using Blender.

For anything else I'd recommend using any of the existing numerous communities like https://blenderartists.org , social network groups or any other forums not focused on coding and development